# GEM ERROR - Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails" -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting a funky error when trying to run my Rails server.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.2, >= 5.2.1)

    trix (~> 0.11.1) was resolved to 0.11.1, which depends on
      rails (> 4.1, < 5.2)
```

I tried checking if it was an issue with the version in my Gemfile and make sure it's the latest, but this didn't help. Also tried installing trix by itself, and updating my version of Ruby, but no luck. Any tips on how to move from here?

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2', '>= 5.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'devise'
gem 'bulma-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'
gem 'stripe', '~> 3.11'
gem 'trix', '~> 0.11.1'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-livereload'
end
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: https://ryanbigg.com/2011/01/why-you-should-run-bundle-update

Comment: Sure downgrade `rails` to a version supported by `trix` or remove `trix`. The error is telling you the exact problem, which is you want `rails` version >= 5.2.1 but `trix` only works with `rails` > 4.1 and < 5.2. So this cannot work since `rails` cannot be greater than `5.2` and also less than `5.2`

Comment: @karma4917 that does not really help since the issue is `trix` and the latest version is `0.11.1` so this would be left alone by bundle update while bundler would try and load some `5.2.x` version of `rails` and the error would still occur

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.